# In SQL, how can I reference a a row with a date that is the closest prior to the date for the row I'm at?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL statement, but it only works if I ALL dates are sequential.  My data does not cover weekdays, holidays or outage days, so there can be gaps of as many as 7 days, so I need a better way to reference the row with the first day immediately prior.

```
update fdd1
    set fdd1.Prior_Open = fdd2.Day_Open,
          fdd1.Prior_Close = fdd2.Day_Close
    from full_daily_data fdd1
    inner join full_daily_data fdd2
    on fdd2.Trade_Date = DATE_SUB(fdd1.Trade_Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would the record with a date immediately prior to a selected record be the MAX date record of the set of records where fdd1.trade_date < fdd2.TradeDate ?  If so, that might form the basis of a subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should calculate the most recent date prior to the `fdd1.Trade_Date` regardless of gaps; the only change from your query is at the end (after `on fdd2.Trade_Date =`):

```
update fdd1
set fdd1.Prior_Open = fdd2.Day_Open,
      fdd1.Prior_Close = fdd2.Day_Close
from full_daily_data fdd1
inner join full_daily_data fdd2
on fdd2.Trade_Date = (
   SELECT MAX(fddsub.Trade_Date)
   FROM full_daily_data fddsub
   WHERE fddsub.Trade_Date < fdd1.Trade_Date)
```